# Django hidden field is not saving to database

Tags: python, django

I am trying to save users IP address in my extended profile model. The goal is to make this a hidden field. Currently, I can debug by printing the IP address to the console. The issue arises when I try and save the info.

views.py

```
def index(request):
    #request.session.flush()
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('ve:dashboard')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.refresh_from_db() # Load the profile instance created by the Signal
            user.profile.birth_date = form.cleaned_data.get('birth_date')
            user.ipaddress = get_ip(request)
            print(user.ipaddress)
            user.save()
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('ve:dashboard')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

forms.py

```
class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    # birth_date = forms.DateField(help_text='Required. Format: YYYY-MM-DD')
    birth_date = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget(years=range(1999, 1910, -1)))
    #ipaddress = forms.IntegerField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'birth_date', 'password1', 'password2',)
        exclude = ['ipaddress',]
```

index.html

```
    <form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in form %}
        <p class="text-left">
        {{ field.label_tag }}<br>
        {{ field }}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
          <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
        {% endfor %}
        </p>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
    </form>
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    ...
    ipaddress = models.CharField(default="0.0.0.0", max_length=30)
```

This form was working fine before I tried adding the ipaddress field. I've been trying several versions and sometimes the form creates a new user but the ipaddress is not saved..

The current code above gives me there error on POST: 
DoesNotExist at / User matching query does not exist. Due to this line "user.refresh_from_db() # Load the profile instance created by the Signal"

Comment: This will *only* save the ip address; all the other data from the form will be replaced when you do `user.refresh_from_db()`. Why do you do that?

Comment: You should use [`GenericIPAddressField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/fields/#genericipaddressfield), you'll benefit from out of the box validation and you can support both ipv4 and ipv6 ;)

Comment: Also note that if you uncomment `ipaddress` from your `RegistrationForm`, it will get rendered in your html as you loop through all fields and render them. If you replace `<form method="post">`'s content with `{{ form }}`, it will render `HiddenInput` correctly ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docs:

> This save() method accepts an optional commit keyword argument, which accepts either True or False. If you call save() with commit=False, then it will return an object that hasn’t yet been saved to the database.

So since you're passing commit in as `False` you're getting an unsaved instance back. Attempting to call `refresh_from_db` on an object that doesn't actually exist in the database will fail, as it is clearly doing. If the instance to a model has no `id` then `refresh_from_db` will fail when called on it.

As for the continuing inability to save IP address, I noticed that your form meta has the model set to the `User` object. The default Django `User` object has no ip address. I see that in the model file you linked you have a `Profile` model that does have an IP Address so in that case I think you simply have your form set up wrong. Or you need to handle the request differently.

**Form change**

Currently your form is attempting to create/modify a Django `User` model. Unless you've made a custom `User` model that you didn't show, this user model will not have an `ipaddress` as a field in the database meaning even if you set `user.ipaddress = <address>` and then save the user, the ip address won't persist outside of the current scope since all you did was declare a new variable for the `user` instance.

If you change your form to point at your `Profile` model you'll be able to save the address using `profile.ipaddress = <address>` and save it successfully. But you will have to update your template since by default it will only show the fields for your profile and not the user object associated with it.

**Change Template/View**

You can also change the template and view to accommodate it. Apparently your view is able to produce an IP Address using the `get_ip` function so for the time being I'll assume your template is fine as is so the only changes that need to be made are to your view.

Currently your view is getting an unsaved `User` instance back when it calls `form.save`. This means you need to save the user and then create a `Profile` model that references it with your ip address attached.

```
def index(request):
    #request.session.flush()
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        return redirect('ve:dashboard')
    elif request.method == 'POST':
        form = RegistrationForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            # do anything you need to the unsaved user here
            user.save()
            prof = Profile.objects.create(user=user, 
                                          ipaddress=get_ip(request),
                                          date=form.cleaned_data.get('birth_date')
            # no need to save prof since we called objects.create
            raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=raw_password)
            login(request, user)
            return redirect('ve:dashboard')
    else:
        form = RegistrationForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the current error message I was getting but the ipaddress field is still not being saved.

Comment: @AlexWinkler Check edit. I may have solved your problem?

Comment: I actually think this was solved elsewhere if I'm understanding what you're trying to do. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7584977/in-django-how-can-i-create-a-user-and-a-user-profile-at-the-same-time-from-a-sin?rq=1) question might cover what you're trying to do too.

Comment: Hey sorry for the delay and thanks for all the help so far. I applied the changes above and all is working now. I did "user.profile.ipaddress = get_ip(request)" instead and removed the "commit=False". The only thing that is left is hiding the field in the template. The Django form prints all the fields.. This only hides the input area, not the label "widget=forms.HiddenInput()," and "exclude = ['ipaddress',]" doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Okay this did the trick. 1. Remove `ipaddress = forms.IntegerField(required=False)` 2. leave `exclude = ('ipaddress',)` 3. keep `fields = ('ipaddress',)`