# Django : Saving two different forms at the same time results two entries in the database

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

Here is my models.py file.

```
class Individual(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    phone_no = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    payment = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user
```

Here is my forms.py

```
class UserRegisForm(ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ['email','password']

class IndividualForm(ModelForm):
    title = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Title'}))
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'First Name'}))
    middle_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Middle Name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Last Name'}))
    phone_no = forms.CharField()
    payment = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = Individual
        fields = ['title','first_name','middle_name','last_name','phone_no','payment']
```

Here is my views.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def register(request):
    next = request.GET.get('next')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = IndividualForm(request.POST)
        form1 = UserRegisForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid() and form1.is_valid():
            user = form1.save(commit=False)
            password = form1.cleaned_data.get('password')
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save()
            form.save()
            login(request, user)
            if next:
                return redirect(next)
            return redirect('existing_module_master')           
        else:
            return redirect('/register', messages.error(request, 'Form is not valid', 'alert-danger'))
    else:
        form = IndividualForm()
        form1 = UserRegisForm()
        return render(request, "register.html", {'form':form, 'form1':form1})
```

And here is my register.html file,

```
<html>
<body>
    <form method="post">
    {{form.as_p}}
    {{form1.as_p}}
    <input type="submit" formmethod="post">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Gives me the following output.. that is, It insert the data in CustomUser first then it keep it blank in Individual. Then it insert again the value in the Individual table by providing null as user_id.
[image]

Please let me know If I'm doing it wrong!

Answer (score -1):

Your form.save() and user.save()

Rather when you get to the point of saving construct an Individual object and save the request.POST['field'] into the correct field on the model. It would be easier to do so seeing that they are coming from 2 different forms.

Comment: The data are coming from two different forms and its saving in the database as well.. but I want to insert the data at the same time rather than provided output.Saving 2 times the data.

Comment: You will always need to create a user instance first and then create an Individual Instance. It is how you have set it up. Individual requires User with a one to one relationship.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7585040 Actually I'm following  this answer. Can you let me know how can I make this working ?